# Prevent toolbar title on navigation icon android

Tags: android, styles, android-toolbar

I have two screen. First one is main screen. There is no toolbar title which has only NavigationIcon. Second one is the other activity. It has a title and HomeAsUpIndicator. I use below style codes to remove gap between title and HomeAsUpIndicator icon in second activity.

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/homeToolbarNavigationButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">8dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">8dip</item>
    </style>

    <style name="homeToolbarNavigationButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">-20dp</item>
        <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
    </style>
```

Although there is no title in the main screen, NavigationIcon is below title when ı use this style. How can solve this problem? Yo can show in images.

Answer (score 1):

I create a custom toolbar .xml and ı added my second activity .xml;

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_custom_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/general_padding_left"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/go_back_icon"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_go_back_icon"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well from your question it seems you want to hide the title in the Second activity. Correct me if I'm wrong

Use `windowNoTitle` attribute in styles to not show Title in toolbar.

```xml
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Alternatively, you can use `setTitle(" ")` in onCreate of the activity.

Comment: Thanks. I use it but not working. I edited question. You can see my problem better.